# How to read the string "500 600" to store two separate variables with values 500 and 600 in C?

Tags: c

I tried using atoi but I can only get to the 500 that way. Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/) to "tokenize" a chain of whitespace-separated integers:

```
int a, b;
char src[] = "500 600";
char *tmp = src;
// The first call to strtol parses 500
a = strtol(tmp, &tmp, 10);
// The call looks the same, but tmp now points at the space between 500 and 600
// The next call to strtol skips the space, and parses 600
b = strtol(tmp, &tmp, 10);
```

Obviously, this code is skeletal, and skips the relevant checks. See documentation for the precise information on how `strtol` handles various unexpected situations.

Answer (score 1):

1. Read the entire string using [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/).
2. Tokenize the string based on the space delimeter using [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/).
3. Convert the token to the integer.
4. If string has more characters, go to step 2.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sscanf` will be simple.
An example to use `sscanf` is as below:

```
char str[] = "500 600";
int a, b;
if(sscanf(str, "%d%d", &a, &b)==2) {
    // OK
} else {
    // failed to parse
}
```

If you do not need to test the `sscanf` has failed or not, write as below:

```
sscanf(str, "%d%d", &a, &b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char &s = "500 600";
int x, y;
if (2 == sscanf(s, "%d %d", &x, &y))
{
/* Everything is ok */
}
else
{
/* Have another go! */
}
```

should do the trick

Comment: Yoda conditions strange indeed are :)

Comment: Naw, they make sense. It puts the value you're testing near the name of the function that emits it, and means you have to look less far down the line to see what the condition you're testing actually is. Besides, this is C, not English.

That said, I write foo() == bar myself.

Comment: Consider making the mistake a=2 (when you meant a==2). The compiler says this is OK. But if you get into the habit of doing 2==a, the compiler will spit it out.